# variables and arguments passing

Tags: python, variable-assignment

When we write the following code:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
a.append(3)
print(b)
```

Here, list becomes [1, 2, 3] for both a and b.
But when I perform the code:

```
a=3
b=a
b+=1
```

Same thing doesn't happen here a=3 and b=4.
So, can someone explain to me the reason for this.
Also, which data type act as list and which as integer for the same.

Answer (score -3):

You are assigning the value of a to b so b becomes 3 then again you add 1 in b so the value of b becomes 4.